# delete file named "~" and unstage from git

Tags: git, macos, unix

I'm not sure how this happened (maybe I typed a command line `vi ~ /extra/space.txt`?) but there is now a file named `~` staged for commit.  I do not want to add it to git, and I'm hesitant to try `rm ~` before thinking through possible side effects.

```
$ git status
On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:
    modified:   apples.js
    modified:   app/berries.js
    modified:   app/views/pears.js
    new file:   app/views/lemons.js
    modified:   public/stylesheets/oranges.css
    new file:   ~
```

Comment: I think I remember someone asking about his `?` directory some time ago... scary stuff indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the backslash to escape it

```sh
rm \~
```

Alternatively, you can use single-quotes to avoid shell interpretation (rather than escaping the shell interpretation)

```sh
rm '~'
```

As the commit is staged, you'll also need to clear it before merging by `add`ing the removed file again (so its absence is incorporated into the staged commit) or `reset`-ing the removed file (this probably happened because you used `git add -a`)

```sh
git add \~
```

While your fears are practical, also don't worry, `rm` won't remove directories, only files, without providing some flag (`-d`, `-r`, `-R`..)

Comment: aha, that worked, thanks!

Comment: @prototype will want to `git rm` it, or `git add` the removal after using plain `rm`. :-)

Comment: that's true, let me add a little about that!